# Why File.write() can't handling the tuple

Tags: python, file, python-3.7

I am developing a Customized File Shredder.

I want to write tuple values bytes inside the files.

**for example:**
If i pass 3 variable (0,100,1) # 'b'00, 'b'd, 'b'01 
and the File Size is 200 Bytes.
for 200/3 = 66 times it will write all the tuple data. and in last round 200%3 = 2 so it will write the first 2 tuple data.
when I tried to implement it, it goes wrong.

When i used write byte mode:

```py
def multiple_writer(self, val:tuple):
    with open(self.file_path, 'wb+') as file:
        file_current = 0
        main_mode = True
        while file_current < self.file_size:
            if main_mode:
                for values in val:
                    if file_current <= self.file_size:
                        file.write(values)
                        file_current += 1
                    else:
                        main_mode = False
                        break
            else:
                break
```

When i used append byte mode:

```py
def multiple_writer(self, val:tuple):
    with open(self.file_path, 'ab+') as file:
        file_current = 0
        main_mode = True
        file.seek(0)
        while file_current < self.file_size:
            if main_mode:
                for values in val:
                    if file_current <= self.file_size:
                        file.write(values)
                        file_current += 1
                    else:
                        main_mode = False
                        break
            else:
                break
```

My Result is :

**When Running Write Byte mode**
[image: When Running Write Byte mode]
**When Running Append Byte mode**
[image: When Running Append Byte mode]
**Required Result**
[image: Required Result]

I Search everywhere and still, I can't find the answer where the bug is happening.

Comment: pls give us a transparent example of calling a function.

Comment: for example :
i have a file size of 650 bytes and a tuple name val. val holds ('b'00', 'b'001, b'002'....n). 
i want a output of : 'b'00' 'b'001 b'002' 'b'00' 'b'001 b'002'... till the end of file size.
so i open the file in 'write mode'.  first i check the condition if the file current position is less than file file size. if yes then write the values in the tuples. here also i am checking for the current position is still less than file size. if the condition failed break all the loop and end the program.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Simplification of the code

If we define a helper function which returns cyclically the data from the tuple:

```py
def cyclic_iter(values):
    while True:
        for v in values:
            yield v
```

then the code could simply become:

```py
def multiple_writer(self, val:tuple):
    with open(self.file_path, 'wb+') as file:
        generator = cyclic_iter(val)
        for _ in range(self.file_size):
            file.write(next(generator))
```

or one could exploit the `zip` function:

```py
def multiple_writer(self, val:tuple):
    with open(self.file_path, 'wb+') as file:
        for _, value in zip(range(self.file_size), cyclic_iter(val)):
            file.write(value)
```

### Edit: Simplest way

Since you mentioned that you just started with python I'll add the simplest way I know.

```py
def multiple_writer(self, val:tuple):
    with open(self.file_path, 'wb+') as file:
        for i in range(self.file_size):
            file.write(val[i % len(val))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it works, because i am new to this community and python language and i am working on my first project. so i tried to find the answer but i can't found.

Comment: No problem! Python it's really simple but it takes time to learn all its nuances. So Good luck!

Comment: `file.seek(0)` and `file.seek(0, 0)` are equivalent, as explained in the documentation you cited.